# Heroku Crossdomain.xml

Tags: xml, heroku, playframework

I would like to place a CrossDomain.xml file in my Heroku app... I have tried, but it just is not being read correctly.  I put it in the assets folder and made a pointer in routes in my play application.  It pulls it up if I type it manually, but Heroku still doesn't play nicely with my other website yet.  Any ideas on how to allow crossdomain from Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You could not do this directly, since Heroku does not allow to store uploaded files for individual apps. But You can use Amazon S3 store service for this purpose. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-s3-for-file-uploads-with-java-and-play-2) .